# jQuery spinner using issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spinner

what i've wrong?
here is code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="<c:url value='/resources/js/jquery-1.7.js'/>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="<c:url value='/resources/js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js'/>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="<c:url value='/resources/js/jquery.ui.spinner.js'/>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="<c:url value='/resources/js/myscript.js'/>"></script>

<input id="spinner" type="text" value="0" />
```

mysript.js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $(function() {
        $('#spinner').spinner({min: -100, max: 100});
    });

});
```

it still doesn't work

btw, it says:
TypeError: this._super is not a function

this._super( key, value );

jquery...nner.js (line375)

TypeError: this._super is not a function

this._super( options );

jquery...nner.js (line  389)

Comment: Is there _super function somewhere in source js files?

Comment: @sergzach yep, it's in jquery.ui.spinner.js. but i think problem is not in that file. i use spinner for the first time, so i don't know how it should be... may be i connected not enough files?

Comment: May be your jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js does not contain all you need. May be you did not check all the required options on the download page (http://jqueryui.com/download/).

Comment: Try to download jquery-ui with all options for a test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/KaaaT/

So you need:

- jQuery
- jQuery UI
- jQuery UI CSS
- spinner

Click on the `manage resources` at the jsfiddle link above to see, which URL's I have used for the example.

The jQuery code:

```
$('#spinner').spinner({ min: -100, max: 100 });
```

The HTML code:

```
<input type="text" id="spinner" value="0" />
```

Jsfiddle uses jQuery UI 1.8.18.
Google's Content Delivery Network hosts a newer one. So I suggest that you use these url's:

- https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js
- https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
- http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css
- http://btburnett.com/spinner/ui.spinner.min.js

**Edit:** The problem is probably that you forgot to add the widget feature to your custom jQuery UI library when you have downloaded it. Try the one hosted by Google's CDN. Or re-download jQuery UI with the `widget` option checked.

Answer (score 0):

you code not any problem,look at:[here is you code](http://jsfiddle.net/yhc13429826359/4tfwK/)

Comment: Just like I said, it's not the code but the wrong/broken jQuery UI. which does not have the widget component in it. He can use the one from Google CDN to test and/or redownload jQuery UI.